# Problema de "AttributeError: __exit__" no Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Num grupo, pedi para me darem dicas sobre algum programa para testar meus conhecimentos. Ele me mandou criar um programa que lê um arquivo chamado `"arquive.txt"` e administra arquivos `CHAR` e `STAGE`, com o arquivo assim:

```
[CHAR]
Exemplo = C:/Users/Usuário/Desktop/New Folder/file1.char
[STAGE]
Exemplo2 = C:/Users/Usuário/Desktop/New Folder/file2.stage
```

Isso é o que eu fiz:

```
import ConfigParser as CP
cfg  = CP.RawConfigParser()

'''
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Olá, bom dia, esse é meu novo programa.
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
'''
h = open('arquive.txt', 'r+')
if h.readlines() == []:
    h.close()
    cfg.add_section("CHAR")
    cfg.add_section("STAGE")
    with open('arquive.txt', 'wb') as fl:
        cfg.write(fl)
    with open('arquive.txt', 'r') as fg:
        print fg.readlines()

class Char(object):
    def __init__(self, nome, caminho):
        self.nome = nome
        self.caminho = caminho
    def addChar(self):
        g = open('arquive.txt', 'r')
        cfg.readfp(g)
        cfg.set("CHAR", self.nome, self.caminho)
        g.close()
        with ('arquive.txt', 'wb') as non:
            cfg.write(non)

inserir = raw_input("Nome do Char: ")
inserir2 = raw_input("Caminho do Char: ")

char = Char(inserir, inserir2)
char.addChar()
```

Mas quando rodo o programa, aparece o erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/root/arquivo.py", line 35, in <module>
char.addChar()
File "/root/arquivo.py", line 28, in addChar
with ('arquive.txt', 'wb') as non:
AttributeError: __exit__
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Está faltando um `open` na linha:

```
with ('arquive.txt', 'wb') as non:
```

Dessa forma, `('arquive.txt', 'wb')` é só uma tupla. O erro é porque o `with` espera um objeto com `__enter__` e `__exit__`, o que uma tupla não tem (mas o valor de retorno de `open`, sim).

O código correto, portanto, é:

```
with open('arquive.txt', 'wb') as non:
```

Comment: xD fiquei mais de 2:30h tentando e nada. Vlw cara!

Comment: @Breno se a resposta lhe resolveu o problema marque-a como correta. [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/3635)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Desculpa, eh que eu achei que nao tinha como, cliquei na seta pra cima e nao pude.